# Saving the options added on top of existing spinner

Tags: android, arrays, spinner

I'm trying to allow user to add more options to existing spinner.
The spinner shows options from existing array list  that I'd created. Users can add options to the spinner but only for as long as the app is running. When it is reopened , the added options are not there which I know why.
I just need to know how do I save those options without using a database.I did find shared Preference methods but they were too complicated.
Your help will be appreciated.

This is the part of array and its addition to spinner.

```
final List<String> spinnerArray =  new ArrayList<String>();
    spinnerArray.add("Grocery");
    spinnerArray.add("Transportation");
    spinnerArray.add("Rent");
    spinnerArray.add("Electricity Bill");

  final  ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerArray);

    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    Spinner sItems = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    sItems.setAdapter(adapter);
```

This is the part of adding new options to spinner.

```
 EditText cat = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText10);
 String cate = cat.getText().toString();
 adapter.insert(cate, 0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to save in SharedPreference as Database would be more boilerplate code. Or you can do File operations. But storing in shared preference is very easy. You can use below methods to do it.

Save array to SP

```
public boolean saveArray(List<String> array, String arrayName, Context mContext) {   
    SharedPreferences prefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences("preferencename", 0);  
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();  
    editor.putInt(arrayName +"_size", array.size());  
    for(int i=0;i<array.size();i++)  
        editor.putString(arrayName + "_" + i, array.get(i));  
    return editor.commit();  
}
```

Load array from SP

```
public List<String> loadArray(String arrayName, Context mContext) {  
    SharedPreferences prefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences("preferencename", 0);  
    int size = prefs.getInt(arrayName + "_size", 0);  
    List<String> array = new ArrayList<String> ();  
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)  
        array.add(prefs.getString(arrayName + "_" + i, null));  
    return array;  
}
```

Now to use in your code all you have to do is -

```
saveArray(spinnerArray,"SpinnerArrayData",getApplicationContext());
```

to get -

```
spinnerArray = loadArray(SpinnerArrayData",getApplicationContext())
```

Comment: I got identifier expected error when saving the array just before using on spinner and then immediately loading it .
Also, when i changed things a bit, I got error of type conversion of String[] to List<String> and vice versa.

Comment: modified for list of string

Comment: I just did that myself but it didn't work either, there were no errors but the value wasn't saved. Any idea where i should be saving the array to SP?
I am saving it just after the user adds any new option and loading it just before using it on the spinner.

Comment: when you do EditText cat = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText10);
 String cate = cat.getText().toString();
 adapter.insert(cate, 0); you only add item to adapter. you should also add to list.  so after this do spinnerArray.add(cate); and then save to pref

Comment: oh ..my bad. Thanks for the help!